# Idiomatic clojure: taking multiple items off a channel

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have a channel into which I am putting a number of individual values (JSON lines, incidentally).

In taking values off the channel, I wish to batch-process them as a group. Is there any notion of `take n` from the channel or else a means to bundle them into a vector/sequence/list?

Comment: Do you know how many values you want to take? What do you expect to happen when not enough values are put onto the channel?

Comment: Blocking would probably be an acceptable response, but I'm not overly fussed at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `clojure.core.async/take` to take a specific number of items off a channel. They are returned in the form of a new channel, so you still have to use `<!`, `<!!`, or `take!` to process them individually. If you want to process them as a group, you can use `clojure.core.async/into` to put them into a standard Clojure data structure.

Comment: The links in the answer are broken. The official docs can be found at https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/take

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that. I've removed the broken links so that when the Clojure documentation moves again in the future, this won't happen again.